# React-Native get UI and JS FPS from RCTPerfMonitor

Tags: react-native

I want to create a performance test case to measure the UI and JS FPS from my react native app.

How can I call the performance monitor and get the FPS programmatically?

(Currently we can enable the Performance Monitor [PCTPerMonitor] from the shake menu.)

Answer (score 1):

We can enable the performance monitor programmatically by the following code

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *settings = [defaults objectForKey:@"RCTDevMenu"];
NSMutableDictionary *newSettings = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:settings];
newSettings[@"RCTPerfMonitorKey"] = @1;
[defaults setObject:newSettings forKey:@"RCTDevMenu"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

After update the setting, it will trigger the notification 'settingsDidChange' from RCTDevMenu.

And we can get the FPS after performance monitor is enable. It will add the performance monitor in the window (should be the last object)

```
UIView *performanceMonitorView = self.window.subviews.lastObject;
for (id view in performanceMonitorView.subviews) {
  if ([view isKindOfClass:[RCTFPSGraph class]]){
    RCTFPSGraph *fpsGraph = (RCTFPSGraph *)view;
    NSLog(@"FPS Graph minFPS: %zd maxFPS: %zd fps: %zd", fpsGraph.minFPS, fpsGraph.maxFPS, fpsGraph.FPS);
  }
}
```

Then we can traverse the performance monitor subviews and save the RCTFPSGraph instance to get the FPS.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to achieve this in Android?